# What does みぞれは雨のような雪です mean?

Tags: translation

I have been translating a NHK Easy news item but I can't get over a sentence.

> みぞれは雨のような雪です。

I understand each word however I can't find out the sentence ultimate meaning.

Comment: Give it a shot at translating, so we can see that you understand each word. It's a straight-forward sentence, like これはペンです, so I don't quite understand where you're having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Noun-A + のような + Noun-B =
> Noun-B like Noun-A
>
> みぞれは雨のような雪です
> Sleet is snow (which is) like rain.

Another example:

> 山田さんのような人を見ました
> I saw a man (Who looked) like Yamada.